# nodejs slow after El Capitan update

Tags: node.js, express, npm, osx-elcapitan

Starting up an express app with "node app.js" is excruciatingly slow after updating to El Capitan. Is anyone experiencing this?

I've reinstalled node and npm, and even turned off SIP, but it still takes minutes to start up an app with node.

Comment: What version of Node are you using?

Comment: Can you test your app elsewhere? I've had no probs with El Cap and any node app.

Comment: I think it may be the indexing. I'll have to compare in a few hours/days if it gets better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this wasn't an issue with the upgraded OS, but with my project and my perception.